# AWS Direct Connect - Diverse Internet Path

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm looking to leverage an existing Direct Connect service as a redundant internet gateway for times when the primary connection goes down.

I note that the NAT Gateway notes specify this isn't possible, has anyone been able to do this using a NAT Instance or similar?

Not finding a lot on the AWS site or elsewhere.

Comment: Do you mean 'a redundant internet gateway' for your office? If you're ok that it might cost you a lot (you'll be billed for DC+all external traffic), you may want to try custom built NAT or even chain of two NATs. I see no reason why it won't work.

Comment: Correct, would like to be able to route web traffic and SMTP through AWS if there's a failure

Comment: Just throwing in that while it is possible, with the easiest way being a VPN Tunnel running on an EC2 instance... Could you maybe contact your direct connect provider and ask them to provide additional routes out of that network?  It's quite uncommon for SMB to directly peer with AWS, and usually use a transit provider.  Those transit links are essentially a closed network, and one of the transit provider routers could be configured to route internet traffic.  Alternatively, if you just want to reuse copper/fibre links, you can likely vlan those links to provide alternative routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VPC is fundamentally **not** a LAN with switches and routers -- it's a software-defined network.  One thing it does not provide is a way to route traffic from edge to edge and transit a VPC -- enter a VPC via one virtual gateway device and leave via another.

You can't come in on Direct Connect or Hardware VPN or a VPC Peering connection and then *directly* leave via a NAT Gateway, Direct Connect, Hardware VPN, or VPC Peering connection -- all of these things are designed around the concept of *accessing instances*, not accessing each other.

The implication of this is that you can't use Direct Connect to *directly* access the Internet -- but you can do this via a server providing tunnel and NAT services, running in EC2 -- cooperating with a tunnel server on your office/data center LAN.

The key concept to overcome is that the traffic must appear to VPC with appropriate IP addresses -- from/to Direct Connect, the traffic needs to be from a LAN address to an EC2 instance, and from/to a (custom-built) NAT instance and the Internet, from/to the IP address of the NAT instance.

A pair of openvpn servers -- one at the office, one in EC2 -- handles this, because openvpn transports the traffic as TLS over UDP -- with the only source and destination IP addresses visible to VPC as those of the machine on your LAN and those of the instance.

The server on your LAN would interact with your LAN router by accepting Internet-bound traffic sent to it via the router and tunneling it to the EC2 instance, which would decapsulate that traffic, and NAT it using its own source IP for delivering it to the Internet -- and on response traffic, un-NAT it and send it back up the tunnel to the LAN for delivery back to the machine that initiated it.